# JQuery: I'm trying to delete the first <br> before the text, but every <br> gets deleted

Tags: jquery

I have this:

```
<p>
<br>
<br>
JQuery problems again...
<br>
<br>
Why me...?
</p>
```

I tried using this:

```
$("p").children(":first-child").nextUntil(":not(br)").remove();
```

But I somehow end up with this:

```
<p>
JQuery problems again...Why me...?
</p>
```

To my understanding, do correct me if I'm wrong, the code searches for the first-child of `<p>`, which would be the first `<br>`, then deletes all of them that appears before the text.

All I want to do is delete the first `<br>`s that appear before the text in a `<p>` element. Can you please tell me how I can do that?

Comment: Your existing code will work if the text is wrapped within another element (`<span>` perhaps).

Comment: text does not count as an element in jQuery's `.next()` logic.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery to see how to obtain text nodes in jQuery or wrap the text in a `<span class="myText">` so jQuery will see it as an element.

Comment: @jfriend00 How Do I wrap the text nodes in a `span` using jquery? I can't edit the html manually.

Comment: I added an answer that works without having to put `<span>` around the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like jQuery doesn't help a whole lot here so rather than try to force it in, this looks like it's a job for plain javascript (other than identifying the `p` tags).  This will work on your existing HTML without adding `<span>` tags around the text.

```
$("p").each(function() {
    var children = this.childNodes;
    var removals = [], child, i;
    for (i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        child = children[i];
        // nodeType 1 is ELEMENT_NODE
        if (child.nodeType == 1) {
            if (child.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "br") {
                removals.push(child);
            }
        }
        // nodeType 3 is TEXT_NODE
        else if (child.nodeType == 3) {
            // stop at first non whitespace text node
            if (child.nodeValue.match(/\S/)) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // now remove the nodes we collected for removal
    // remove outside the first loop because childNodes is a live array
    // and we don't want it changing while iterating it
    for (i = 0; i < removals.length; i++) {
        removals[i].parentNode.removeChild(removals[i]);
    }
});
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/NjaRF/

Answer (score 1):

CSS selectors can never match *text* per se—only elements. jQuery doesn’t have that much support for matching text nodes. I guess you’d have to do something like this:

```
$("p").each(function () {
  $($(this).contents()).each(function () {
    if (this.nodeType === 3 && /\S/.test($(this).text())) {
      // Found some text, so stop removing elements.
      return false
    } else if ($(this).is("br")) {
      $(this).remove()
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change your HTML to this where the text is in a span:

```
<p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span>JQuery problems again...</span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span>Why me...?</span>
</p>
```

You can then use this jQuery to remove those leading 
 tags:

```
$("p br:first-child").nextUntil(":not(br)").andSelf().remove();
```

See it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/W2W5F/

Comment: It is on Blogger, and I can't add `span`s to comments manually.

Comment: Then, you're stuck with searching for text nodes manually like in Daniel's example.  I was just offering something different if you had control of the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a quite old question, but I found this topic when I faced a similar problem today.

I've just found an alternate - and simple - solution, maybe it will be useful for someone:

```
$('p').each(function(){
    var h = $(this).html().trim();

    // remove <br> tags before text
    while (h.match(/^<br ?\/?>/gi)) h = h.replace(/^<br ?\/?>/gi, '').trim();

    // remove <br> tags after text
    while (h.match(/<br ?\/?>$/gi)) h = h.replace(/<br ?\/?>$/gi, '').trim();

    $(this).html(h);    
});
```

JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ULwCL/